# GLSL Phong-Shader Specular artifacts

Tags: glsl, shader

I'm having some specular issues with this Phong-Shader, It generates a weird output.
(Pay close attention to the model's ears):
[http://i.imgur.com/1n3gYvn.gif](https://i.imgur.com/1n3gYvn.gif)

Also, it has a weird behaviour on plane surfaces:
[image: Weird]

Here's the shader code:
Vertex+Fragment: http://www.pasteall.org/59832

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In line 79 of your shader code, change dot(R,E) to max(dot(R,E),0.0). It's because you don't want to give your surface a shinny look when the angle between R and E is bigger than 90 degree as shown in the attached illustration when the eye is at Eye2. [Here](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/tutorials/ClockworkCoders/lighting.php), at section *Implementing Phong Shader*, provides a useful GLSL template for Lambertian lighting model that you may find useful.

[image]